# WebService attributes

Tags: web-services, wsdl

I am creating a web service that generates the following in the WSDL file:

```
<wsdl:portType name="myServicePortSoap">
```

and would like to have it renamed to generate:

```
<wsdl:portType name="myServicePort">
```

How can I do that within the .asmx file to do so? Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently specifying the Name parameter in the WebServiceBinding attribute is supposed to affect this but I couldn't see the change in the WSDL.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any way to do this in .NET 2.0. HOWEVER, this is possible thanks to the WCF extensions... Check out the link below:

http://blogs.msdn.com/trobbins/archive/2007/02/04/wcf-and-wsdl.aspx

Answer (score 0):

.asmx? I assume you are using ASP.NET to auto-generate your WSDL?

I'm not sure how you would override the port identifier, or why you would want to; perhaps you are looking to [alias your Web methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(VS.71).aspx#vbtskusingwebmethodattributemessagename)?